# Crashlytics not included but uploading dSYM to Fabric

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using the twitter SDK in my iOS project and I've not included crashlytics e.g. I have this in my AppDelegate.

```
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter class]]];
```

The problem I have is that it looks like 1gb of contents was uploaded to crashlytics, does anyone know why this would happen? From what I can see in the mac console app, it uploads dSYM logs using the run scripted added in the project build phase could that be the culprit?

Thank you for your time and help.

Jing Jing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

This sounds a bit odd, but if the Run Script Build Phase was invoked, then the dSYMs would be uploaded to Fabric. That script is separate from the Fabric init.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike, are their any issues with removing this run script from the build phase? I only need twitter and don't need any crash reporting or analytics from Fabric.

Comment: Nope, you can remove it then. I'd just check your Fabric dashboard for notifications that there is an update to the SDK. The run script build phase can do that for you if you keep it in, but it's completely your call!